# Color picker that sends events per color pick

Tags: c++, user-interface, colors, wxwidgets, color-picker

Does anyone know of any alternatives to the wxColourPicker included in wxWidgets 2.9.3? I was hoping for two things 1) that was non modal, 2) on to go in the wxPropertGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had the need to extend wxColourPicker to support alpha channel I cannot find a replacement, so I wrote a C++/CLI wrapper for a C# color picker dialog.

It may be a PITA at first, but you can extend your application faster when the wrapper is set up - at the cost of your application depending on the .NET framework.

If you need a modeless color picker/editor in C#, look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/WinFormsColorEditor.aspx

Hope this helps.